# "Close as duplicate" dialog doesn't count deleted answers but Duplicate tab does, in the close-vote review queue

Tags: bug, review, deleted-answers, close-dialog

**UPDATE**

With the [restyling of the Close/Reopen review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360198/visual-design-changes-to-the-review-queues), this appears to have been fixed, as that particular dropdown doesn't (seem to) exist anymore.

---

When reviewing [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/close/76882) close vote, I saw that the duplicate question on the "Duplicate" tab in the review queue showed "4 answers" (1 answer, 3 deleted answers):

[image]

Because I have 10K+ and can therefore view deleted posts.  But in the Close as Duplicate dialog, it shows "1 answer":

[image]

Which makes it just slightly confusing.  Can there be a 10K check to fix that, if there isn't one already?

Comment: This seems to have been fixed with the re-styling of the Close/Reopen review queues.